# Resize an HTML element using touches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, touch

Using nothing more than the jQuery lib; I am trying to resize an `DIV` when dragging it's right border. It works perfectly with a mouse but I can't make it work on a touch device. I think it's related to the `e.touches`.

I have tryied using `e.touches` and `e.targetTouches`; none of them seem to work.

Am i implementing the `touch events` part right ? What am i missing ?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TRJp/13/), and the full code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container"><div class="handle"></div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{background:#CCC;width:200px;height:100px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.handle{cursor:e-resize;height:100px;width:2px;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;background:red;}
```

**JS:**

```
var handle = null;

$(".handle").on('mousedown touchstart', function(e){
    handle = {
        x : e.pageX,
        p : $(this).parent(),
        pw: $(this).parent().width()
    };

    if (e.targetTouches){ //e.touches
        handle.x = e.targetTouches[0].pageX //e.touches[0]
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on({
    'mousemove touchmove':function(e){
        if(handle) {
            if (e.targetTouches){ //e.touches
                handle.p.width(handle.pw+(e.targetTouches[0].pageX - handle.x));  //e.touches[0]               
            }else{
                handle.p.width(handle.pw+(e.pageX - handle.x));                    
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    'mouseup touchend':function(e){
        handle = null;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you opened your javascript console or inspector to see if there is any error popping up? Just to know if the events are really firing properly on your touchscreen device.

Comment: @marcioAlmada thanks, actually console.log() isn't firing at all when appended under if(e.touches) or if(e.targetTouches)

Comment: Amazing, even after over 11 years the above still works and on mobile too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `e.targetTouches` you should use `e.originalEvent.touches`.

Allso it would help to have:

- `gesturechange` event alongside `mousemove touchmove`
- `gestureend` event alongside `mouseup touchend`
- `gesturestart` event alongside `mousedown touchstart`

Another improvement would be to on document mousemove event callback move `e.preventDefault()` in the if statement, that way the user can scroll the page if the handle is null .

Comment: Thanks! It worked, this is exactly what i was missing! Since i am binding using jQuery, i need to reach to the OriginalEvent!

Answer (score 1):

I suffered with the same problem when doing a web application, and found this [jquery touch plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/downloads/list) which solved my problem.

Download this plugin and include in ur html file and youre done. You dont need to call any touchstart/touchmove events .

If it doesn't work you can add the touch event like this :

```
$('Element').addTouch();
```

Call `addTouch()` method for every element, that you whant to respond to a touch event.

Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) link for more download options .